# Where do I find module `rtsx_usb_sdmmc.c`?

Tags: drivers, realtek, card-reader

My SD card reader has stopped working.

I want to see if it works again using the above-mentioned module driver. However, I cant find it anywhere. It is not available at all on the computer.

I also have no idea how to use a site like https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=1d14310abb74011dc5523baf0aee75b94070861a.

thank you.

Comment: `rtsx_usb_sdmmc.c` in itself isn't a module - it's a C source code file from which you would need to build and install the module. The module itself should already be provided by one of the system's standard kernel packages. Please [edit] your question to include the output of commands `modinfo rtsx_pci_sdmmc` and `lsmod rtsx_pci_sdmmc`.

Comment: thankyou. i updated my kernel and the module is on but the device hasnt started working so i guess it a hardware problem .    morri@morri ~ $ modinfo rtsx_pci_sdmmc
filename:       /lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/kernel/drivers/mmc/host/rtsx_pci_sdmmc.ko
description:    Realtek PCI-E SD/MMC Card Host Driver
author:         Wei WANG <wei_wang@realsil.com.cn>
license:        GPL
srcversion:     F65CB05294273E6CBE55FA9
alias:          platform:rtsx_pci_sdmmc
depends:        rtsx_pci
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.6.0-040600-generic SMP mod_unload modversions